# How to use windows.h in C/C++ to control other programs' volume control

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm looking for a way to be able to control the volume of different programs without using the Volume Mixer but with C/C++ code. I know the `windows.h` library should be able to do it. But it's huge, and I have no idea where to even start to look.

I've already found that [`nircmd`](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) does exactly what I need with:

```
nircmd setappvolume chrome.exe 0.15
```

Although I could use that command, I would like to write my own and use a hardware device for controlling those volumes.

If anyone has a few links or tips to get me started, I would appreciate it!

EDIT:

I've now used `system()` in C together with `nircmd`, and it works very well. This code just uses a sinus to change the volume starting from 50% going to 100% and 0%.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    char command[100];
    char appName[] = "chrome.exe";
    int i = 0;

    while(1){
        i++;
        sprintf(command, "nircmd setappvolume %s %f", appName, sin(i/10.0)/2+0.5);                        
        printf("%d %% \n", i);
        system(command);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no public API to do this, unfortunately.  The only thing you can set is the master volume.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I've found in my reserach. But finding that nircmd worked, I thought it should be possible.

Comment: Yes, they must have done a bit of reverse engineering.  Perhaps there are some keys in the registry you can set - after all, those volume settings must be stored somewhere.

Comment: thankfully nircmd has a pretty open license. So I'll just use it for my program.

Comment: WASAPI - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/wasapi

Comment: https://matthewvaneerde.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/windows-audio-render-volume-settings-from-local-to-global/ (but that only gives you access to the per-application volume control for the current app)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has the WASPI for controlling audio volume of various clients and output devices.

You get the `IAudioVolumeLevel` interface for a the client, and manipulate each channel using `SetLevel`.

You may need `IMMDeviceEnumerator`, `IDeviceTopology`, `IAudioSessionControl2`, `ISimpleAudioVolume` and other interfaces to do what you want.

So, it's possible, it is documented, but it is non-trivial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/wasapi